# Frontend help: How do I add buttons to webpage flask webpage that allow me to interact with a flask webpage?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, flask

Let's say I'm building a blogging website using flask. On the page to view a post, I want to have some buttons that allow the user to interact with the post (delete, edit, flag as spam, etc.). I have already created the functions in flask to handle each of these actions. What I am not sure how to do is create buttons that allow the user to call these functions. I would like to create the buttons using [bootstrap's vertical button group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-vertical) but I am not sure how to make clicking these buttons run an action. I tried making each of them the submit button of a form, but doing so breaks bootstrap's grouping functionality. Does anyone know a way I can make buttons interact with the flask back-end while retaining bootstrap's grouping functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set "onclick" attribute of your button:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

And then write javascript function with call to flask backend, for example:

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "FLASK_URL_HERE", function() {
    alert( "success" );
})
```

Did i understood your question correct?

Comment: will that send a POST request or a GET request to FLASK_URL_HERE?

Comment: it will send a POST request and it uses jQuery library.
If you need something else you can check jQuery docs here:
http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: Okay, so it sends a POST request. How do I enclose information (such as what user sent it or what action the user wants to do) in that request and how do I get flask to extract that information?

Comment: you can set "data" parameter in your javascript post function and get this info from request.data inside flask view function. Here is the link to flask docs: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#accessing-request-data

Comment: how would I set the "data" parameter in the javascript post? Sorry, I have very little experience with javascript

Comment: its ok :) here is example - $.post( "FLASK_URL_HERE", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );